# PSpice error: '*$' is not a model parameter name

Tags: pspice, orcad

I am using OrCAD PSpice Student Edition, version 9.0, fairly old version (1999) but its what we have access to.

I've had this problem almost every time I use custom parameters for any model, which is requested of me for every Lab simulation. The process I usually do is click the model I want to edit (usually a transistor or MOSFET), go into:

[image]

and then click on Edit Instance Model (Text):

[image]

This prompt then pops up where I paste the custom parameters, terminated by '*$*:

[image]

When I try to run any simulation after, I almost always get an error stating:

```
ERROR -- '*$' is not a model parameter name
```

Removing the *$ terminator gives me another error entirely, so it is supposed to be there, I just don't know where. Is this a problem with how I formatted the lines perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When i edit model parameters i never add $ at the end of the line. But then again, i live in 2019...

Comment: Alex, Just remove the \*$. The '*' is a comment character. But it only works if it is the first character of the line. I think, somehow, a CRLF line termination was removed and a comment was brought up to the prior line (not good.) This could be about differences between the way Windows and Linux handle text files, so it's not an uncommon problem to show up like this. (Your reason might be different, of course. But that may be the reason.)